# ContentArea function with Dynamic contnet?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the `ContentArea()` function to pull  content blocks into various emails, one of the content blocks is dynamic, this function does not seem to work with dynamic content blocks, I thought about doing an `IF/ELSE` to pull in the required content dynamically as needed but I was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, you would not be able to use the `%%=ContentArea()=%%` Function to pull a dynamic content area.

If you're looking to retrieve content areas dynamically in this manner, you would want to code this directly in your email.  This would be achieved by using `IF/ELSE` AMPScript Functions. See below for an example and links on these two topics:

The below AMPScript is setting a variable equal to an attribute in your account called `[Gender]`.  You would then pull one content area if Male, another for Female, and another as a default.  Hope this helps!

```
%%[ 
Var @Gender 
Set @Gender = [Gender] 
]%% 

Your Gender:  %%=v(@Gender)=%% 

%%[IF @Gender == "Male" THEN]%% 
%%=ContentArea("20")=%% 
%%[ELSEIF @Gender == "Female" THEN]%% 
%%=ContentArea("22")=%% 
%%[ELSE]%% 
%%=ContentArea("23")=%% 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

[AMPScript Syntax Guide](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)

[ContentArea Function](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#ContentArea)

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping your `Gender` profile attribute/DE column in the `AttributeValue()` function: `set @Gender = AttributeValue("Gender")`.  Your scripting will fail if `Gender` doesn't exist.  The `AttributeValue()` function will just return an empty string in that case.